# Finding the number that is reapeated consecutively the most in a vector

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
essaie <- "23690,55050,127789,64253,130127,63093,63093,63093,108374,63093,63093"
essaie_z <- c(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(essaie, ","))))
```

I want to know which number repeats itself consecutively the most and how many time it does. Basically, I want to know:

Number that repeats itself consecutively the most: 63093
How many times: 3

How can I do that in r?

thanks,

Comment: What do you want to do if there are two numbers that have the same max?

Comment: @sindri_baldur bad duplicate suggestion. This has the **consecutive** requirement, which makes it substantially different. (There probably is a good dupe out there, but that one isn't it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function [rle](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/rle):

```
runs <- rle(essaie_z)
max(runs$lengths)
# [1] 3
runs$values[which.max(runs$lengths)]
# [1] 63093
```

Explanation `rle` stands for [run length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). It reports the runs in the data as well as the lengths of these runs, returning the result as a list:

```
> rle(essaie_z)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:8] 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 2
  values : num [1:8] 23690 55050 127789 64253 130127 63093 108374 63093
```

What you are asking for is the value which corresponds to the longest run.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works on a vector. I tried it on a tibble but I couldn't get it to work. I posted a new question on how to get a run length in a tibble: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755481/how-to-find-the-longest-duplicate-sequence-in-a-tibble-column

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative,

```
i1 <- strsplit(essaie, ',')[[1]]
l1 <- split(i1, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.numeric(i1)) != 0)))
l1[which.max(lengths(l1))]
#$`6`
#[1] "63093" "63093" "63093"
```

And to get the length,

```
length(l1[which.max(lengths(l1))][[1]])
#[1] 3
```

Not sure how you want your output.

```
 paste0('value: ', unique(l1[which.max(lengths(l1))][[1]]), ', Repetition: ', length(l1[which.max(lengths(l1))][[1]]))
#[1] "value: 63093, Repetition: 3"
```